# Trying to get the number of roles a user has (Discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to get a number of roles that the mentioned user has, however, I was unable to find a way for him to bring the number of positions other than the member who executed the command,
that is, the BOT just ignores the mention and brings the number of roles only to the author of the command. My code:

```js
const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;

const roles  = message.member.roles.cache;
//just an embed
  {
        "name": "️ Roles:",
        "value": `${roles ? roles.map(c => roles.length) : 'None'}`
  },

message.channel.send({ embed })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is only getting the roles of the user that sends the message. You are creating a `user` variable that contains the mentioned user, but you never use it at all in your code. You are only using `message.member.roles.cache` which gets the roles of the author of the message only.

Use `guild.member()` to convert `user` into a `GuildMember` and then use that.

```
const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;

const roles  = message.guild.member(user).roles.cache;
//just an embed
  {
        "name": "️ Roles:",
        "value": `${roles ? roles.array().length - 1 : 'None'}`
  },

message.channel.send({ embed })
```

Relevant resources:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=member

Comment: now a new error has arisen, it does not return the number of roles, it only returns a comma

Comment: I've edited the answer. It should be fixed now. It was probably caused by `roles.map(c => roles.length)` returning an array instead of a number and the fact that there is no such property as `roles.length`. I'm also now subtracting 1 from the role count, because the [@]everyone mention counts as a role for every user by default. If the problem still exists after this edit let me know.